# Enable send logging to a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, logging

I have set up a send logging DE. So far so good. On the salesforce help I see that I have to enable the send logging to a data extension option: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_enable_sendlogging_useror_triggered.htm&type=5

Maybe I am blind but where can I enable this? I don't see that option.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask customer support to 'enable Send Logging option' during the Email Send Process.